# onmouseover eventlistener onto all children

Tags: javascript, dom-events, onmouseover

I have a problem with the `onmouseover()` event listener.

```
<div class="parent" onmouseover="myfunction()">
   <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

I trigger a javascript function whenever the mouse is hovering over the `parrent`, but whenever I'm hovering over the `child`, it doesn't register the `onmouseover` anymore.

Is there a workaround so the `onmouseover()` also gets triggered while hovering over its `child` elements, using pure Javascript?

Comment: It would be good to understand what [event delegation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687296/what-is-dom-event-delegation) is

Comment: Use a delegated event, ie on the parent listen for events bubbling up, then get the event target. Don'r know how to do that in vanilla js. Or maybe mouseenter event may suit your needs?

Comment: Please provide a fiddle that illustrates the issue. I cannot reproduce this problem: the `mouseover` event triggers both for the child as the parent element.

Comment: Does your `myfunction` return true or false?

Answer (score 7):

Use [**mouseenter event**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseenter) instead, which doesn't bubble with children elements like `mouseover`does.

In other words with `mouseover` the event will be attached to all the element `children` too, so when you hover a *child* the event will be fired as if we left the *parent* `div`.

**Demo:**

```js
document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("mouseenter", function(event) {
  var target = event.target;
  console.log(target.id);
}, false);
```

```css
.child {
  min-width: 50px;
  min-height: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.parent {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="test" class="parent">
  <div id="child1" class="child">1</div>
  <div id="child2" class="child">2</div>
  <div id="child3" class="child">3</div>
  <div id="child4" class="child">4</div>
  <div id="child4" class="child">5</div>
</div>
```

You can see in the above snippet that using `mouseenter` the event is always firing even if we hover over children and only the parent `id` is logged, as if we didn't leave it.

**Mouseover demo:**

You can see the difference here using `mouseover` event:

```js
document.querySelector(".parent").addEventListener("mouseover", function(event){
  console.log(event.target.id);
});
```

```css
.child {
  min-width: 50px;
  min-height: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.parent {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div id="child1" class="child">1</div>
  <div id="child2" class="child">2</div>
  <div id="child3" class="child">3</div>
  <div id="child4" class="child">4</div>
  <div id="child4" class="child">5</div>
</div>
```